# iPad device doesn't support a stable version of indexedDB error

Tags: cordova, ipad, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, indexeddb

after opening my phonegap app in iPad it shows error `index.html , your device doesn't support a stable version of indexedDB.`

but it works fine in all other device (android and iphone)

i have tried adding the [IndexedDBShim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) as script in index.html file, but didnt worked. i have also tried using cordova plugins in config.xml as follows 
[`<plugin name="com.msopentech.indexeddb"/>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-indexedDB)
[`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-indexeddb-async"/>`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-indexeddb-async)

but non worked. please let me know if anyone have faced this problem earlier and solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of the Safari installed in the iPad. If your Safari version is < 10 IndexedDB is not supported.

Comment: thanks for the info. is there any way to add additional support for indexedDB in this type of situation ?

Comment: No there are no additional support. You have to go for fallback to localstorage if data to be stored is less.

Comment: To add to this, reference CanIUse.com for these features - it's fantastic.  http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb